# Error in application connecting to MS SQL server in OS startup

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working in a desktop application (C#,Windows Forms,MS SQL Server).
One of the application requirements is to start when the pc starts so I put a
value in the registry under the following key

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**

(I'm working on a machine with windows 7 home edition)

when the application start I check that sqlserver service is running before I load the first form
I also checked for the SQLBrowser service and it's running.

the code for checking the service status

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
if (services.Where(s => s.ServiceName == ServiceName).FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
    using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(ServiceName))
    {
        sw.Start();
        while (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 300000)
        {
            sc.Refresh();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

but when I make first connection with database an exception occurs with the following description

```
Cannot open database "xyz" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ABCUser'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at CheckValidConnection(String ConnectionString)
```

I tried to connecte with windows user, sa user, other user created for the applications with all the privileges on the database
but the result is the same

I think it's not a connection string problem or user privileges problem because if I start the application manually it works fine and also as a final solution I delayed the start of the application for 30 seconds (after the check of the service running)  and it works fine (but I don't like this solution)

I appreciate any help in this problem

**Update**
(Thanks for Nick.McDermaid for directing me to the Errorlog)
I checked the sql server error log and found the following lines

```
2018-02-22 14:10:49.19 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-02-22 14:10:49.19 Logon       Login failed for user 'ABCUser'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2018-02-22 14:10:57.05 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-02-22 14:10:57.05 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 

<local machine>]
2018-02-22 14:10:57.27 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-02-22 14:10:57.27 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 

<local machine>]
2018-02-22 14:10:58.92 spid20s     A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid17s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid16s     Starting up database 'ReportServer'.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid18s     Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid19s     Starting up database 'xyz'.
```

so I think the problem is I'm trying to connect to the database before it's able to receive requests (I don't understand well what is meant by ' Starting up database

'xyz' ')
I tried to check the database status before the first interaction with the database by 2 ways

1- Using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
var server = new Server(scsb.DataSource);
if (server.Databases.Contains(scsb.InitialCatalog))
{
    Database db = server.Databases.Cast<Database>().FirstOrDefault(dbase => dbase.Name == scsb.InitialCatalog);
    if (db == null) return false;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    while (db.Status.HasFlag(DatabaseStatus.Normal) == false && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 60000)
    {
        server.Refresh();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    if (db.Status.HasFlag(DatabaseStatus.Normal) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
else
   return false;
```

2- Using direct query to system table in master db

```
scsb.InitialCatalog = "master";
string CheckOnline = "";
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString))
{
    scn.Open();

    while (CheckOnline != "ONLINE" && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 60000)
    {
        CheckOnline = scn.Query<string>("SELECT state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @DBName ", new { DBName = OriginalDBName }).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
sw.Stop();
if (CheckOnline != "ONLINE")
{
    return false;
}
```

the problem now is both techniques returns the online status of the database before it's actually online 
Is there another way to check if the database is actually online

Comment: Login to SSMS using the same credential which is provided in the connection string. are you able to connect?

Comment: @saTech yes I'm able to connect using SSMS and as I mentioned before I'm able to login manually after the PC starts with the same connection string

Comment: The best solution might be to transparently add some error trapping and retries.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid your suggestion could be a work around but I'm looking for the real reason behind this error. Thanks for help

Comment: I think the real reason is that SQL has not yet started up properly. You might want to take a look at the SQL Server log and see if there is any more info on the login failure there.

Comment: SQL Server Log might also clarify why it's taking so long.